# How many digits are used to arrive at Math.Round answer?

Tags: c#, .net

When using Math.Round are all decimal places considered when doing the 'round' or just the number to the right of the decimal position we are rounding to?

Example;

```
decimal myNumber1 = 0.2651m;
decimal myNumber2 = 0.2650m;

Math.Round(myNumber1, 2) gives 0.27
Math.Round(myNumber2, 2) gives 0.26
```

I would expect both to be 0.26 as the 4th decimal place is not considerd for the rounding.

Comment: What is wrong with what is specified in *Remarks* in [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I had wrongly assumed that when rounding 0.2651 to 2 decimal places that the 3rd position would be the only one used. I now understand that when the documentation says 'the value to the right' it does not mean '5' but rather '51' or '510000001' etc which is clearly beyond the halfway point of 5 and 5+1

Answer (score 4):

> the 4th decimal place is not considerd for the rounding

This is not true.

According to MSDN, [`Math.Round(decimal)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s2d3xkk.aspx) uses a rounding type of [`MidpointRounding.ToEven`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx).

The Midpoint Rounding specifies the rounding behavior when the value to be rounded is exactly halfway between the two possible rounded values.

For example,

- `0.2649` will always round to `0.26`
- `0.2651` will always round to `0.27`

when rounding to two decimals.

What's interesting is what happens in the case of `0.2650`: by default, using `MidpointRounding.ToEven` you get:

- **`0.26`** for `Math.Round(0.2650,  2)`
- `0.28` for `Math.Round(0.2750,  2)`

That's because the rounding is done towards the even most significant digit after rounding (`6` in the first case, `8` in the second).

If, however, you were to use `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero`, you'd get:

- `0.27` for `Math.Round(0.2650,  2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`
- `0.28` for `Math.Round(0.2750,  2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)`

Comment: Ehm, `ToEven` means `x.50000` will be rounded to `x` *if it is even*. If `x` it's odd, the result will be `x+1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want 4-th decimal digit then simply use `Math.Truncate` before rounding:

```
Math.Truncate(0.2651m * 1000) / 1000; //0.265
Math.Truncate(0.2650m * 1000) / 1000; //0.265
```

Answer (score 0):

all decimal places are considered.
rounding 0.2650000001m will result in 0.27 as well